# Convert to float in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to convert my column data type from `varchar` to `float`. The column contains numbers and NULL.

What I need is calculating the avg of the places which are not NULL.

That's my code:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
    ALTER COLUMN column_name float
GO

DECLARE @mean_column_name real;

SELECT @mean_column_name = AVG(column_name) 
FROM table_name
```

I got this error

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

I also tried

```
 DECLARE @mean_column_name real;

 SELECT @mean_column_name = AVG(column_name) 
 FROM table_name 
 WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL
```

but I got the same error

How should I do that?

Comment: There was nothing on Google on how to convert a varchar column to Float?

Comment: firstly why is the column in varchar? and show us the contents of the column.. pretty sure there are columns and lots of dots there..you will need cleansing before you can even convert

Answer (score 0):

You clearly have values in the column that are not valid for conversion.  In SQL Server 2012+ you would do:

```
select @mean_column_name = AVG( try_convert(float, column_name ))
from table_name ;
```

That is not supported in 2008.  So, use a `case`:

```
select @mean_column_name = AVG( case when column_name not like '%[^0-9.]%' and column_name not like '%.%.%' then convert(float, column_name) end)
from table_name ;
```